# How do I work around the error "ByRef return value not supported in reflection invocation" in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke, ref

I have a .Net library supplied by a third party.  I did reflection on one of their classes and found a member method.  The signature was...

```
Byte& FooBar()
```

So, I wanted to call this method through reflection and got the exception "ByRef return value not supported in reflection invocation."

Here is what I've tried...

```
        var strm = new TheirClass();
        var t = strm.GetType();
        var ms = t.GetMembers(
                    BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var m in ms)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}: {1}", m.Name, m.ToString()));
            // ...
            // Name: FooBar:  Byte& FooBar()
            // ...
        }
        var meth = t.GetMethod("FooBar");
        object returnValue = meth.Invoke(strm, new object[] {  });  //throw exception
```

I have tried supplying parameters as in calling functions with ref parameters, but that made no difference.

I would like to work around this exception in C#.

Comment: Interesting, but the exception seems kind of clear though - the function returns a reference to a byte and invocation doesn't support functions that return references (why, I do not know... perhaps in case something on the stack is returned). Is the method public, perhaps it could be called via a managed C++ DLL?

Comment: @T.Kiley - agreed, the exception is clear, i.e., "Not Supported".  But my question is how to work around it.  Yes, perhaps C++DLL would do, but I would like to work around in C# if possible.  I will update the question.  Thx.

Comment: Would TypeDescriptors be worth having a mooch at.  I know they provide additional metadata capabilities over reflection, Im sure there is some invocation stuff in there too.

Comment: It cannot work like this, because it returns a `ByRef` type, `ByRef` types aren't objects, and the `methd.Invoke` return type is `object`, so it would have no way to return the result. It should be possible to use a delegate type which has a `Byte&` return type, and then use `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` to create an instance of that delegate type, but such a delegate type cannot be written in C# either. I don't see any way out of this other than not using C#. If a `DynamicMethod` built from C# is acceptable (personally, I'd prefer it over C++/CLI), I can post an answer using that.

Comment: @hvd - Using a DynamicMethod would be acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the comments: here is how it can be done from CIL, which can be generated from C#.

I was hoping to use a `DynamicMethod`, but I cannot manage to get this working without creating a custom delegate type at runtime, so I needed to use `AssemblyBuilder` instead.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public delegate void CallBadFunction(Delegate d, Callback c);
public delegate void Callback(ref int i);

static class Program
{
    static int i;
    static object BadMethod()
    {
        return i;
    }

    static MethodInfo GetBadMethod()
    {
        return typeof(Program).GetMethod("BadMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var badMethod = GetBadMethod();

        var assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("-"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("-");

        var badDelegate = module.DefineType("BadDelegateType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Sealed, typeof(MulticastDelegate));
        var badDelegateCtor = badDelegate.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(IntPtr) });
        badDelegateCtor.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.Runtime | MethodImplAttributes.Managed);
        var badDelegateInvoke = badDelegate.DefineMethod("Invoke", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), Type.EmptyTypes);
        badDelegateInvoke.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.Runtime | MethodImplAttributes.Managed);
        var badDelegateType = badDelegate.CreateType();

        var method = module.DefineGlobalMethod("-", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(Delegate), typeof(Callback) });
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, badDelegate);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, badDelegateInvoke);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Callback).GetMethod("Invoke"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        module.CreateGlobalFunctions();

        var callBadFunction = (CallBadFunction)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(CallBadFunction), module.GetMethod("-"));
        callBadFunction(badMethod.CreateDelegate(badDelegateType), (ref int i) =>
        {
            i++;
        });
    }
}
```

After compiling this program, use ILDASM to disassemble it, and replace `BadMethod`'s definition by

```
.method private hidebysig static int32&
        BadMethod() cil managed
{
  ldsflda     int32 Program::i
  ret
}
```

This turns it into a function returning `int32&`, which the following code will then manage to call. The only location C# allows `int32&` types is in function parameters (`ref int`), so to make the result usable, I used a callback function, which gets passed the return value of `BadMethod`.

Comment: You put me on to something when you suggested a DynamicMethod.  I am marking yours as the answer because your approach can apply more generally.  But take a look at what I came up with after your earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you "hvd" for pointing me in the right direction.  After some thought, here is what I came up with.  It's simpler, but please tell me if you see a flaw.

```
        var theirObj = new TheirClass();
        var t = theirObj.GetType();
        var fooBar = t.GetMethod("FooBar"); // Byte& FooBar()

        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod(
            "MyFooBar",
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
            CallingConventions.Standard,
            typeof(IntPtr), 
            new Type[] { typeof(TheirClass) },
            typeof(TheirClass),
            true);

        var ilg = dm.GetILGenerator();
        ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Call, foobar);
        ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var del = dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TheirClass,IntPtr>));
        var ret = (IntPtr)del.DynamicInvoke(theirObject);

        byte[] buf = new byte[theirObj.FooBarSize()]; //no need for reflection/IL here
        // not sure about the following, it works, but should it be inside an "unsafe" section?
        Marshal.Copy(ret, buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

I put a simple wrapper around the offending method and IL doesn't care that I treat the Byte& as an IntPtr.  I'm still not sure about doing a Copy without an unsafe wrapper.  But this is good for now.

Comment: Oh, that's clever! It's risky though. The runtime may (and does) move objects around in memory unless you lock them to a fixed address, and if this happens, raw pointers don't get updated to the new location. It does show that my answer is more complicated than necessary, though. I was needlessly trying to avoid creating a new dynamic method for every function being wrapped, but of course I can just hardcode the `MethodInfo` exactly like you're doing.